# Facebook problems sharing utf-8 encoded text strings

Tags: facebook-graph-api, utf-8

I'm trying to understand what is happening on my page, some users complained that text is not visible when they try to share my links...

For example: [facebook dev page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fholiday.ge%2Fevent%2Fdj-gela-dj-bene%2F)

og tittle is fine: `og:title:`  but look at description: `og:description:   ÐŸÐ¾ÐºÐ° Ð¶Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ð¸ Ð²ÑÐµÑ Ð¿Ð»Ð°Ð½ÐµÑ‚Ñ‹ Ð±ÑƒÐ´ÑƒÑ‚ Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð¶ÐµÑÑ‚Ð²ÐµÐ½Ð½Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ð·Ð´Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð’ÑÐµÐ¼Ð¸`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://holiday.ge/event/dj-gela-dj-bene/:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 570 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
>
> The error was: utf8 "\xE1" does not map to Unicode

Comment: hm, this seems to be causing it: <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,115); ?> I'm changing this to mb_substr.

Comment: Yes, you can not use the normal PHP string functions with UTF-8 content – because they operate on bytes, not chars.

Answer (score 0):

Your page does not even have "og:description", it usually just works fine if you put in the correct metatag. I know that the YOAST SEO plugin (the one you are using) does allow you to set up a description for every article, just below the article text in the edit window there is an input field called "Meta Description".

Comment: That's not an issue here. Some articles don't have description, and fb scrapper is just grabbing text from the surrounding, this is ok for me. Cbroe pointed out problem.

Comment: well, it´s always good to put in a description. much better for SEO if you control what´s there ;) - and also less problems with the encoding then.